# HTML Summary tag in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Is there any way to use the summary tag in Internet Explorer (version 11) (an external library for example).

```
    <details>
    <summary>This is a summary.</summary>
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
    </details>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE doesn't support `summary` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make them work yourself, since IE doesn't support them.

You can feature-detect `details`/`summary` like this:

```
if (typeof HTMLDetailsElement === "undefined") {
    // No, not intrinsically supported
}
```

If they aren't intrinsically supported, in order to style them, you'll need to tell IE they exist, which you can do by simply creating and throwing them away:

```
document.createElement("details");
document.createElement("summary");
```

Then (again only if not intrinsically supported) add some styling for them:

```
// JUST A ROUGH SKETCH
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.textContent = 
    "details > :not(summary) {\n" +
    "    display: none;\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "details.showing > :not(summary) {\n" +
    "    display: block;\n" +
    "}\n";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);
```

Of course, not all elements that will be within `details` will normally have `display: block`, so you'll have to tweak that. (For instance, you might use a `div` for all the non-`summary` content.) You may also want to add an arrow on the left or something so it's similar to how Chrome and Firefox render these.

**Atypically**, you'll want the code doing the above to be *before* the `body` element to avoid a flash of unstyled content.

Then respond to clicks on `details` elements and space/enter keypresses on them by toggling the `showing` class that styling defines:

```
// AGAIN: THIS IS A ROUGH SKETCH
document.addEventListener("click", detailsHandler);
document.addEventListener("keypress", detailsHandler);
function detailsHandler(e) {
    if (e.type === "keypress" && [13, 32].indexOf(e.which || e.keyCode) === -1) {
        return;
    }
    var el = e.target;
    while (el && el.tagName !== "DETAILS") {
        if (el.tagName === "BODY") {
            el = null;
            break;
        }
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    if (el) {
        el.classList.toggle("showing");
    }
}
```

This code doesn't have to be before `body`, it can be in your normal location. But as it's conceptually part of the initial bit, it may make sense to put it there.

Then ensure that you use `tabindex="0"` on both `details` and `summary` so that IE will include them in the tab order:

```
<details tabindex="0">
<summary tabindex="0">This is a summary.</summary>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
</details>
```

Live example:

```html
<!-- In the head element -->
<script>
(function() {
    if (typeof HTMLDetailsElement === "undefined") {
        // Tell IE they exist
        document.createElement("details");
        document.createElement("summary");
        document.addEventListener("click", detailsHandler);
        document.addEventListener("keypress", detailsHandler);
        var style = document.createElement("style");
        style.textContent = 
            "details > :not(summary) {\n" +
            "    display: none;\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "details.showing > :not(summary) {\n" +
            "    display: block;\n" +
            "}\n";
        document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);
    }
    function detailsHandler(e) {
        if (e.type === "keypress" && [13, 32].indexOf(e.which || e.keyCode) === -1) {
            return;
        }
        var el = e.target;
        while (el && el.tagName !== "DETAILS") {
            if (el.tagName === "BODY") {
                el = null;
                break;
            }
            el = el.parentNode;
        }
        if (el) {
            el.classList.toggle("showing");
        }
    }
})();
</script>
<!-- End of in the head element -->

<!-- In body -->
<details tabindex="0">
<summary tabindex="0">This is a summary.</summary>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: The complete code snippet has a bug (which you already seem to have fixed in the small code snippets above it). The CSS code it injects will set display: block; for every subnode matching "details.showing :not(summary)", which will mess up elements which have another display value.

Comment: @Spellcoder - Thanks for letting me know! Just so I'm sure I'm fixing the right thing, the issue is the descendant combinator instead of the child combinator? (E.g., I'm missing `>` on those two rules?) Or is there more to it? That's the first thing I see that's different but...

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, IE11 does not support summary/detail. For those just finding this, here are some polyfills you can try using to support IE11:

- https://github.com/javan/details-element-polyfill
- https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-details